# How do I crop an image using RenderScript?

Tags: java, android, crop, renderscript

I want to be able to crop an image using RenderScript. Here is my crop function:

```
uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) crop(const uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y){
    int minX = centerX - cropWidth;
    int maxX = centerX + cropWidth;

    int minY = centerY - cropHeight;
    int maxY = centerY + cropHeight;
    uchar4 out = in;

    if((minX < x < maxX ) && (minY < y < maxY)){
        return out;
    }
    else{
      out.r = 0;
      out.g = 0;
      out.b = 255;
      return out;
    }
}
```

This is the desired logic:
If the pixel is not in the X Y bounds specified in the IF condition, then I want that pixel to be blue.

For some reason, no matter how strict my bounds are, *none* of the pixels are blue. Can someone explain to me why this is?  And how to fix it?
If I replace the IF condition to just false (`if(false)`, so it guarantees execution of the ELSE code), then all pixels are blue (as expected).

Comment: I switched an over-broad tag for a more specific one and polished code formatting/indentation and grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
minX < x < maxX
```

isn't working the way you are expecting it to. What that code is doing is first checking if `minX < x`, then casting the resulting Boolean to an Integer (will be 0 or 1), and finally checking if that Integer is less than `maxX` (which it will always be). (Same thing is happening with the `y`'s). You need to rewrite that check like:

```
(minX < x && x < maxX ) && (minY < y && y < maxY)
```